# Django : Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'music/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django Environment (current version : 1.11.4) , I am trying to get an HTML Page to see the issue but  getting an exception:

```
   NoReverseMatch at /music/
Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'music/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']
```

Some of the files I am taking in consideration are :

**index.html**

```
{% extends 'music/base.html' %}
{% block body %}
{% if all_albums %}
<ul>
{% for album in all_albums %}
<li>
    <a href="{% url 'music:detail' album.id  %}">{{album.album_title}}</a> </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% else %}
<h3>No Album Found </h3>
{% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = 'music'

urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^$',views.IndexView.as_view(), name = 'index'),

    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name = 'detail'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.views import generic
from .models import Album
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView , UpdateView , DeleteView
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy



class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'music/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_albums'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Album.objects.all()


class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Album
    template_name = 'music/detail.html'
```

and my **base.html** file has nothing but a navigation bar with some functionalities to follow. I just did everything to make it work but till the time I am unable to do so , could you please help me in it ?

**EDIT:**

**models.py**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

# Create your models here.

class Album(models.Model):
    artist = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length = 500)
    album_title = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
    album_logo = models.CharField(max_length = 1000)


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('music:detail', kwargs = {'pk': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.album_title + ' : ' + self.artist

class Song(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album , on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    file_type = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
    song_title = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
    is_favourite = models.BooleanField(default = False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.song_title
```

Comment: Is that the exact error message you get for that exact template? The full error message should say which line the error is occuring on. Is it definitely that line of the `music/index.html` template that is causing the error?

Comment: Actually It shows error on the line where I've included  `bootstrap.min.js` in `base.html` template . But I don't see any point in it , Why would Bootstrap has any relation with this error ?

Comment: the page that gives you the error, what URL is it?